# Which server is this HTTP exception coming from?

Tags: .net, web-services

The scenario is I have received a file for processing via my web service. Because it has errors, I am sending the file back to the originator via his web service, with the errors annotated. I'm assuming that because the file was barely under the 4MB limit, the annotations have made it too big. What I'm not sure of is whether the "maximum request length exceeded" error is coming from my server or his. I believe it is on his end since his server is trying to read the request, but I need to confirm that.

(To complicate reading the stack trace, the file I am sending is called a "response" file.)

```
2010-12-16 11:01:07,009 [724] ERROR MyResponseHandler [] - Unable to send response.  
Exception: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException  
Message: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.  
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()  
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream()  
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()  
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()  
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)  
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)  
Source: System.Web.Services  
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)  
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)  
   at MyServiceProxy.UploadResponse(String callerIdentifier, String serviceName, String referenceIdentifier, String content, String contentFormat)  
   at MyResponseHandler.UploadResponse(MyRequest request)  
   at MyResponseHandler.TransmitAllResponses()
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting. I didn't realize it would recognize this as code.

Comment: well do you have `MyResponseHandler` in your code? If so this error is yours. Otherwise it's his.

Comment: MyResponseHandler is the method in my code that threw the error that it couldn't send the file back to the originator. (It isn't really called that; I redacted some organizational information.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is coming from the other end ->

```
 System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
```

Also because it says `maximum **request** length exceeded` in `MyServiceProxy.UploadResponse` which I believe is yours uploading the fileback.

I assume they have a service and need to up the [MaxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that was my interpretation as well, but I needed to be sure of myself before I tell this client that the problem is on their end. They can send me smaller files to allow for my annotations or they can up their MaxRequestLength.